# When IE8 is not IE8 what is $.browser.version?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

IE8 can go into IE7 mode if it needs to. How does jQuery detect this? Specifically, what is the value of `$.browser.version`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE8 in IE7 mode will report IE7.
BUT you can analyse user-agent and check for "Trident/4.0". If you see this line then you work with IE8

Comment: IE 8 in "IE7 Standards Mode" still reports "8.0" from $.browser.version.

Answer (score 6):

The `$.browser` obejct is populated using a concept know as **Browser-Sniffing**. Put simply, this is the processes scanning data out of the user-agent string which is sent by browsers, robots, and anything else that accesses the page.

Due to the susceptiblity of the user agent to faking, this object is deprecated in later versions of jQuery. Object Detection and Feature Detection (see `$.support`) are now used in preference.

For example, Opera 8.5. used to identify itself as IE:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml

**$.support:**

http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.support

**User Agents:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm

**Object detection:**

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html
http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/objectdetection.html

**Browser Sniffing:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_sniffing

**Feature Detection:**

http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.support

Comment: well, yeah that's nice, but which out of the `support` properties tells me if IE supports `inline-block` properly? `leadingWhitespace, tbody, objectAll, htmlSerialize, style, hrefNormalized, opacity, cssFloat, scriptEval, noCloneEvent, boxModel`

Comment: Not sure if any of them would do that. You could try extending the .support function (see example at: http://www.waytoocrowded.com/2009/03/14/jquery-supportminheight/), or maybe there's even someone that has extended this already. This is a bit of unknown teritory for me, though.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this out myself (having just downloaded IE8)

When you put IE8 into IE7 compatibility mode with the meta tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

The value of `$.browser.version` is *still* 8.0!

Answer (score 1):

JQuery can only see what the browser tells it.

In IE7 mode the browser will report itself as IE7, so that is what JQuery will see.

Comment: And what the browser tells it can be a lie

Comment: Well, kind of... When in IE7 mode everything should be as if the browser really was IE7. The browser is reporting the version of the rendering engine, not the actual version of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a .NET developer and I always like to use a [Sessions.aspx](http://www.balexandre.com/Sessions.aspx) page that I created for this kind'a problems

Fell free to use it, I can share the code as well.

as you can see by this screencast that I just made (14 sec) you get MSIE 8 and MSIE 7 specified in the javascript navigator property, they change when you change compatibility mode as the engine that renders the page is slight different (remember that is not 100% IE7 engine!)

instead of using the jQuery buit in method, just use the normal javascript

**IE8 in IE7 mode**

> 4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 7.0**; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB6; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)

**IE8 in native mode**

> 4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 8.0**; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB6; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)

code:

```
var browserVersion = navigator.appVersion.toLowerCase();
if(browserVersion.contains('msie 8') ) {
    // IE 8
}
else if(browserVersion.contains('msie 7') ) {
    // IE 7
}
```

> **Screen cast video**: http://www.balexandre.com/temp/showFlash.aspx?swf=2009-08-19_1138_ie8ie7.swf&w=952&h=742

Comment: Wow, that sessions-page is reaaaally outdated