# In Javascript, how do I determine if my current browser is Firefox on a computer vs everything else?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(firefox and is on a computer){
alert('using firefox on a computer')
}else{
alert("using something else!");
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What does "is on a computer mean" ? Do you want to also detect iphones and other mobile deveices ?

Comment: Why do you want to know that?

Comment: because the q says if firefox AND is on a computer ? The is on a computer must be important otherwise it wouldnt be there.. after all its redundant otherwise.

Comment: Note that Firefox on iOS uses WebKit rather than Gecko rendering engine due to a policy enforced by Apple on iOS apps. You have to keep in mind, if you want to detect the brand name of the browser, or the rendering engine.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

What you're after is known as browser detection:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) { ...
```

However, browser sniffing is discouraged, as its easy to spoof the user agent, i.e. pretend to be another browser!

You'd best use feature detection, either in your own way, or through the `jQuery.support` interface: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Here's an article on extending it for your own use:
http://www.waytoocrowded.com/2009/03/14/jquery-supportminheight/

**Edit:**

Found this post as well which helps: [When IE8 is not IE8 what is $.browser.version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298713/when-ie8-is-not-ie8-what-is-browser-version/1298738#1298738)

Comment: You mean discouraged? ;) +1 for feature detection, please do it 'the right way': http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/12/29/feature-detection-is-not-browser-detection/

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: Brilliant article, by the way. I realised that I didn't properly understand feature detection. Have you posted that in an answer? Because I'd happily vote it up!

Comment: I don't agree with your "the right way". Spoofing the user agent is not done for evil purpose, but to workaround developer bugs. So it's better trust what user wants you think he is.. he has better reason than you

Comment: Sometimes you will still need to find out what the agent is and make a best  guess. I'm pretty sure (not 100%!) that I can detect if Java plugin is already installed and enabled, but there is no JavaScript "feature" that can report if it's even possible. I know that Java is supported in Firefox for a tiny bit longer (not much!), so I have to use sniffing. That is just an example, though-- you can imagine that other technologies will be platform-dependent yet not exposed as a JavaScript feature. +1 to this answer for me.

Comment: This is depreciated and removed from the latest jQuery

Comment: It outputs: "TypeError: $.browser is undefined", because this property was removed from latest versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 45):

I am doing some thing like below;

```
function checkBrowser(){
    let browser = "";
    let c = navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome");
    let f = navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox");
    let m8 = navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE 8.0");
    let m9 = navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE 9.0");
    if (c > -1) {
        browser = "Chrome";
    } else if (f > -1) {
        browser = "Firefox";
    } else if (m9 > -1) {
        browser ="MSIE 9.0";
    } else if (m8 > -1) {
        browser ="MSIE 8.0";
    }
    return browser;
}
```

Comment: You're introducing global variables, and this does not look like a robust way to check this. For instance, this detects Edge as "Chrome"

Comment: Please have a look at the date of my answer, let was introduced later.

Comment: You don't need `let` to avoid global variables, you can use `var`, since the beginning of JavaScript's history.

Comment: @1j01 Yeah, you are right, please share a proposed better version

Comment: Well the global leaks are fixed now, but I don't know what the best version of browser detection is; it would need a lot of data and browser testing. And really, you need to keep in mind what the goal is, for instance, if you want to display the name of the browser someone's using (there are hundreds!), or to to target a specific rendering engine to avoid a bug (there are only a few).

Answer (score 17):

Like this: Check for Firefox. Or some other browser.

```
 window.onload = function() {
          //  alert(navigator.userAgent);
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) {
                alert("ff");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 14):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {

 //some specific code for Mozilla

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to detect features you need, not a browser. For example, if you need to know if foo() is supported, you can check it with if(foo){}

Answer (score 4):

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
  var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
  var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
  if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
  M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
  return M.join(' ');
 })();
```

as the name suggests, this is who the browser **says** it is- 
but use object detection before asking it to actually do anything...

I use it for logging errors from users and in testing code in multiple browsers- where I know the userAgent strings.

Answer (score 3):

For a quick and dirty solution just do the following, it is cleaner to use includes() when you are searching the 'Firefox' keyword in the `NavigatorID.userAgent` property than indexOf().

```
const isFirefoxBrowser = navigator.userAgent.includes('Firefox');
```

**WARNING:**

> Browser identification based on detecting the user agent string is
>   unreliable and is not recommended, as the user agent string is user
>   configurable.

[Read more about userAgent on MDN >>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent)

**RECOMMENDED SOLUTION:**

Use feature detection instead of browser detection.

> Feature detection involves working out whether a browser supports a
>   certain block of code, and running different code dependent on whether
>   it does (or doesn't), so that the browser can always provide a working
>   experience rather crashing/erroring in some browsers.

[Read more about implementing feature detection on MDN >>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection)

Comment: While this code may answer the question but adding an explanation of the code would be helpful to future readers.

Comment: I don't really get it. How do I detect that the browser is Firefox via feature detection? For example, to direct user to `addons.mozilla.org` so that they can install my add-on?

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) { ...
```

Comment: this property was removed from jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can make the control with javascript's `navigator.userAgent` or `navigator` object in general,

But if you want to use something ready to go, check this:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

hope this helps, Sinan.

Answer (score 1):

As already asked in a comment: why do you want this? Browser sniffing is a bad habit and there are only a few situations where it is needed.

Instead, use feature detection. As [**described by Nicholas Zakas**](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/12/29/feature-detection-is-not-browser-detection/), you should test relatively 'uncommon' features before using them and only rely on these tests, so you're kind of fail-safe. For example, do

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

instead of

```
if ((brwsr.IE && brwsr.IE.version >= 7) || (brwsr.firefox) || (brwsr.opera))
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

And also **don't** do

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    // Hey, native XMLHttpRequest-support, so position: fixed is also supported
```

(instead, test if `position: fixed` is supported)

There exist several uncommon browsers with names like [Kazehakase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazehakase) and [Midori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_%28web_browser%29) that also might, or might not, support these features, so your scripts will silently work on them when using feature detection.

But please read the [**mentioned article**](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/12/29/feature-detection-is-not-browser-detection/), as it contains a very good and thorough explanation of this technique. (By the way, I think that Zakas' [*Professional JavaScript for Web Developers*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047022780X) is still too unknown.)

Comment: It'd be nice if this always worked. But sometimes you have a case where features are implemented slightly differently in different browsers, but this difference isn't declared in a variable. For instance, I'm trying to deal with the problem that you can't copy text from disabled fields in firefox, but you can in every other browser. So I need to switch to using the readOnly attribute in firefox. There's no way to detect this other than knowing the user agent.

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined'
```

It's simple and works well after Quantum but not sure whether this will be future-proof though: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InstallTrigger

Comment: Firefox now reports "InstallTrigger is deprecated and will be removed in the future."

Answer (score 0):

Any solutions that are mentioned here are not safe because the agent does not always provide the correct browser name in the first place. If you call a page with chrome you also have safari in the agent. That means if safari is the first thing to happen with an if query then you have safari on elseif you have no elseif and only if then the override is overridden in this case safari. This solution is not the safest but it always takes the smallest index to get the first one. Opera is the other way around, opera is at the very back of the agent, so other browsers may differ.

```
/**
 * Description of Browser
 *
 * @author      Samet Tarim
 * @link        http://www.tnado.com/
 */    
var _MBT_Browser = {
    client: {},
    __init: function () {

        console.log('Init Browser...');

        _MBT_Browser.client.agent = navigator.userAgent;
        _MBT_Browser.set();
    },
    set: function () {

        var browsers = ["Firefox", "MSIE", "Trident", "Safari", "Chrome", "OPR"]; // Set the browser we want to detect
        _MBT_Browser.get(browsers);
        if (_MBT_Browser.client.current) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-useragent', _MBT_Browser.client.current); // Ad HTML tag data-useragent="IE"
        }
    },
    get: function (browser) {

        var index = '',
            i = 0,
            max = 0,
            min = 1000000; // to get the min value, we set first to million, is a placeholder for the first loop

        for (; i < browser.length; i++) {

            index = _MBT_Browser.client.agent.indexOf(browser[i]); // get index

            // Special case, we need here the largest index
            if (browser[i] === "OPR") {
                if (index > -1 && index > max) {
                    min = index;
                    _MBT_Browser.client.current = browser[i].toLowerCase();
                }
            } else {
            // We hold only the smallest index number and overwrite on smaller
                if (index > -1 && index < min) {
                    min = index;
                    _MBT_Browser.client.current = browser[i].toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Use:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    _MBT_Browser.__init();
});
```

And use with CSS to style on the browser:

```
[data-useragent="firefox"] {
    /* Attribute has this exact value */
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use `navigator.userAgent` for this. Just see if it contains *Mozilla*

Comment: Pretty much everything includes the string *Mozilla* … including Safari on the iPhone! This is useless for determining if Firefox is being used, it is useless for determining if a computer is being used!

Comment: Have a look at http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/12/history-of-the-user-agent-string for a detailed history of the infamous *Mozilla* tag.