# Detect firefox browser with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, browser

I facing a problem is my css is have a some bug when firefox is lower than 2.0.
I would like to detect the browser to fix my css bug.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready ( 
 function() {
  if ( $.browser.mozilla == true && $.browser.version < '3.0' ) {
   $('img.frameMargin').css('margin-left','35px');
  }
 }
);
```

But this code seem like not work.

Thank for advance.

Comment: I'd really like to point out that `feature detection` trumps `browser detection` in both scalability and maintainability. I think you may want to have a look at `$.support.boxModel` instead.

Comment: See @richardneililagan's comment. Feature detection really is probably the way to go here. It will be more future proof in case the browser makers change their release number format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do this...

```
$.browser.version < '1.9'
```

FireFox 2 should return 1.8... so this will pass.

Comment: jQuery api docs recommend AGAINST using $.browser. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ ..  also better to use feature detection than checking browser user agent that can be spoofed.. $.browser tests for user agent.. the jQuery api says to use $.support.. but in this case try testing if window.mozInnerScreenX exists..

Answer (score 30):

This has been answered already in this discussion: 
[In Javascript, how do I determine if my current browser is Firefox on a computer vs everything else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324944/in-javascript-how-do-i-determine-if-my-current-browser-is-firefox-on-a-computer)

To answer your question from that post, thanks to "BalusC" for the answer:

```
var FF = !(window.mozInnerScreenX == null);
if(FF) {
    // is firefox 
} else { 
    // not firefox 
}
```

Above posts advise to use jQuery.browser. But the jQuery API recommends against using this method.. (see [DOCS in API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)).

jQuery API recommends to use 'jQuery.support' (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/). 
The reason being is that `jQuery.browser` uses the user agent which can be spoofed and it is actually deprecated in later versions of jQuery. It's better to use feature detection instead of browser detection.

**UPDATE:**

jQuery.browser is now removed from jQuery as of version 1.9

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

if you really need to use it.. jQuery.browser has been ported over as a separate jQuery plugin

https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

I just bumped into this problem myself. $.browser.version actually **detects the version of the rendering engine**, and not the version of the browser (despite what its name implies), so if you want to detect Firefox **4** and later, you should use

```
$.browser.mozilla && $.browser.version > '2'
```

Because Firefox **4** uses Gecko **2.0** as the rendering engine. It's rather confusing, I know :)

Answer (score 1):

On my machine (Mac OS X 10.6), `$.browser.version` in Firefox 4 reports `"2.0"`. So, it looks like your code is valid, but there's an issue with JQuery.

From the [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/](http://JQuery%20docs):

> We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support).

If you need reliable browser detection in Javascript, check out one of the many tutorials online (such as [this one](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/CSS-Browser-detection-using-jQuery-instead-of-hacks.aspx)).