# How to set an appropriate image depends on user agent type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let I've an image:

```
<img src="URL1"/>
```

I want that the src attribute will be `URL1` only for `Firefox` browsers but `URL2` for others browser. Is it possible to do?

Comment: See here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352522/how-can-i-detect-browser-type-using-jquery). After detecting the browser you can set the image src accordingly.

Comment: It is possible, although user agent detection is messy and generally discouraged. But there are JS libraries to do it. Basically you'd need to have an `onload` event which checks the browser and adjusts the image URL

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Javascript, how do I determine if my current browser is Firefox on a computer vs everything else?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324944/in-javascript-how-do-i-determine-if-my-current-browser-is-firefox-on-a-computer)

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible. Try this.

```
if (!(window.mozInnerScreenX == null); ) {
      // Change your image
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser agent by using Jquery

```
if(jQuery.browser.mozilla){
    // Change your image for URL1
}else{
    // Change your image for URL2
}
```