# In Java Script validation Using keyup for validating is not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup, jquery-form-validator

In jquery form validation the keyup is not working mozilla but working fine in chrome.

here is the Javascript code

```
function validate() {  
    var msg;  
    if(document.myForm.userPass.value.length>5)
        msg="good";  
    else
        msg="poor";  
    document.getElementById("mylocation").innerText=msg;  
}
```

here is the html code

```
<form name="myForm"> 
<input type="password" value="" name="userPass" onkeyup="validate()">   
Strength:<span id="mylocation">no strength</span>  
</form>
```

Comment: works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jfnuvd8u/)** You try wrapping your code in `head` and if possible try to keep it on `keypress` for key press and hold event **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jfnuvd8u/1/)**

Comment: it working in chrome but not working in mozilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359822/2065039)** it tells that ***Firefox doesn't take `innerText` or `innerHTML` to set a value, rather it takes `textContent` to set a value***. So use `textContent` to set your value if the browser is **Firefox**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jfnuvd8u/2/)**

```
function validate() {  
    var msg;  
    if(document.myForm.userPass.value.length>5){  
        msg="good";  
    }  
    else{  
        msg="poor";  
    }  
    var f=navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox"); //check if browser if FF
    if(f>-1)
        document.getElementById("mylocation").textContent=msg //if yes use this
    else
        document.getElementById("mylocation").innerText=msg //else normal approach
}
```

> **Note :- As I suggested in comment use `onkeypress` instead of
> `onkeyup` for key `press` and `hold` events validation.**
>
> **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jfnuvd8u/3/)**

To identify different browsers you can use below code from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172194/2065039)**

```
function checkBrowser(){
    c=navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome");
    f=navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox");
    m8=navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE 8.0");
    m9=navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE 9.0");
    if (c>-1){
        brwsr = "Chrome";
    }
    else if(f>-1){
        brwsr = "Firefox";
    }else if (m9>-1){
        brwsr ="MSIE 9.0";
    }else if (m8>-1){
        brwsr ="MSIE 8.0";
    }
    return brwsr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jquery, it will work in each browser

```
function validate() {  
console.log("validation start");
    var msg;  
    if($("input[name='userPass']").val().length >5)
        console.log("good");//msg="good";  
    else
       console.log("poor");// msg="poor";  
    document.getElementById("mylocation").innerText=msg;  
}
```